# How is 'regretting a mitzvah' defined?

Tags: halacha, mitzvah, reward-punishment

What constitutes regretting a mitzvah: Does one have to write down a regretful statement, speak the regret, think it explicitly, or is a tinge of fleeting regret enough to qualify as regretting a mitzvah?

As a contextual example (also pertinent to Chaye Sarah parsha viz Avraham and Sara's death and Akeida mitzvah) https://www.dailyhalacha.com/WeeklyParasha.asp?ChumashID=1&ParashaID=5&ParashaClipID=469

"If a person struggles to wake up early to attend the Minyan, but attending the Minyan causes him to miss a lucrative business opportunity, if he then regrets going to the synagogue he forfeits all the benefits of that Misva"

Comment: what about regretting "regretting a mitzvah?"...would that offset the regretted mitzvah back into the status of a mitzvah again?

Answer (score 3):

Rambam Laws of Repentance Ch.3 states that a formulation of the heart suffices

> Rambam, Laws of Repentance, Chapter 3
>
> (1) If someone regrets the commandments that he has performed and wonders regarding his merits and says in his heart, "What did I gain by doing them? I wish that I had not done them," this person loses all of them, and no merit in the world is mentioned for him.

Comment: You came back to answer you own question; that's awesome!!

Comment: ......I wanted to do you a favor and link to the Rambam directly, but I can't seem to find it [here](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/1503.htm). Which halacha is that, in that perek?

Comment: It may sound like from those words that it may have to be a deep type of regret since it says he says in his heart which his emotions

Comment: @Shokhet it is halacha 3

Comment: @user9749 heart is not sposific emotions but anything inside as can be seen in the naming of the book "duties of the heart"

Comment: @daniel +1 but it might be only if all the mitzvot , one sposific mitzvah might be different see http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/72991/5120