# If a Jew was forced to do a mitzva, does it count?

Tags: halacha, mitzvah, reward-punishment

If a Jew was forced to do a mitzva (For example, if we grab him and put tefilin on him.):

1. Has he fulfilled his obligation? For example, if he was forced to say shma and then made teshuva (and now wants to say it) is he obligated to say shma?
2. Does he receive reward?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. From Shulchan Aruch Harav [475.28](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/sh/sh3/1/475/28)

It seems that it will depend if it is a mitzvah that his body gets benefit from I.e. Matza, moror, and the Korban Paisach

If yes, then he has done the mitzva.

But if it is no pleasure for his body I.e. shma, shofar, lulav (and tefflin) then he has not yoitze the mitzva and it is not called that he did a mitzva (even if he was not forced just that he did not have in mind to do the commandment)

2. from Hilchos Talmud Torah [4.3](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/sh/sh5/6/4/3.htm)

it seems he might get some reword since he is doing what the Rabbis commanded "to do the mitzva not for its sake" (we know it is a mitzva to listen to the Rabbis for this reason we say a brocho on shabos candles)

---

PS @MichaBerger referred me to [rambam  Mishneh Torah »Sefer Madda » Teshuvah - Chapter Three](http://m.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/911896/jewish/Teshuvah-Chapter-Three.htm)

> Halacha 3.
>   Anyone who changes his mind about the mitzvoth has performed and regrets the merits [he has earned], saying in his heart: "What value was there in doing them? I wish I hadn't performed them" - loses them all and no merit is preserved for him at all as [[Ezekiel 33:12](http://m.chabad.org/16131#v12)] states "The righteousness of the upright will not save him on the day of his transgression." This only applies to one who regrets his previous [deeds]...

(For commentaries regarding this see [this](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=1&hilchos=5&perek=3&halocha=3&hilite=) in Hebrew)

From which it seems that even if his body had pleasure if he regrets (at a later time) that he performed the mitzva it is lost.
But it is possible that this only works if it is all the mitzvot that he had performed not only one

Comment: This seems to contradict something that I have heard numerous times from numerous rabbanim when I was in elementary and high school. Limud Torah is a mitzvah. Many students, including myself, were lazy or reluctant to learn anything. We'd rather be outside playing punch ball. But, we were forced to learn and every rebbe explained the principle "mitoch lo lishma ba lidei shema", loosely translated as when you learn without doing so for its sake eventually you will do it for its sake. But, it was explained that you accomplished a mitzvah either way.

Comment: @DanF  you can ask that as a separate question but I think that's it is not a different opinion since the same author likes your idea in the laws of Torah study if I'm not mistaken

Comment: @DanF my answer was Tony regarding if he fulfilled his obligation not if it is considered a if he has done a commandment

Comment: "Tony"??? I don't understand.

Comment: @DanF regarding the Commandments to study Torah by children it is the Father's command to teach them so his intent is what is important

Comment: @DanF anF Tony = only.....

Comment: OK, got it, now. Regardless, I believe that even when forced, they have fulfilled their obligation. Another case - in my kids' high school, all boys are required to come to morning minyan and sit there with their tefillin on their arms and heads even if they don't daven, and even if they have no interest in their own fulfilling the mitzvah or any kavanat mitzvah at all. The rebbe told me that they still fulfill obligation of wearing tefillin. Also, how about all these Chabbad guys who force Jews to put on tefillin when they are reluctant? If the wearer doesn't fulfill the mitzvah, why bother?

Comment: @DanF it is hard to imagine that they force, I think it will be considered they convince

Comment: @DanF the mitzvah of tefflin is not connected to prayer

Comment: @DanF http://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/sh/sh5/6/4/3.htm it can be seen from here that shelo lishma is dirabonon since they were the ones that said you should do it anyway, and it is a mitzva to do a mitzva dirabonon

Comment: @DanF yesterday i got it wrong, it is not only regarding the obligation but he did not make the mitzva at all, good yom tov kabolas hatorah bsimcha ubpnimius

Comment: @LN6595 thank you for correcting my mistake, next time please ping me to that i will know i got it wrong (this time i was editing the answer and saw it)

Comment: Should be added: If he i angry about being forced and regrets doing it... Regret can cancel a mitzvah. http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/48359/how-is-regretting-a-mitzvah-defined

Comment: @MichaBerger wow! thank you! I added this

Comment: Good, There are Mitsvot Asse that Kofin oto ad sheyomar Rotse Ani. Get, etc. 
המתעסק בחלבים ועריות חייב שכן נהענה
It may be true for Averot too. when a profit/pleasure come.

Comment: @kouty thank you, is that not for the conclusion that he made the get and not for the mitzva of giving the get, so the get was given but the mitzvah might not have been made?